# How to display Filename into a readOnly textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Here's a little thing i want to achieve. I have an asp.net FileUpload and a textbox. When a user clicks the fileUpload and selects a picture from his/her computer/device, i want the image name to be immediately displayed in a textbox before submitting . Here is what i have tried

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="Upload" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" /> 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtImage" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">

$('#Upload').change(function () {

               var filename = $(this).val();
               var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
               if (lastIndex > 0) {
                   filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
               }
               $('txtImage').val(filename);
           });
```

It still cant get it displayed. wHAT AM I MISING PLEASE

Comment: $("txtImage") - missing a # or .? Id or class? $("#txtImage"). Also check to see if you get any console errors.

Comment: Your comment did help me out. I added the # which solved part of it. Also, had issues with my jquery reference. That has been sorted out. It's working well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `#` in `$("txtImage")`. This should be like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("ready!");
            $('#Upload').change(function () {

                var filename = $(this).val();
                var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
                if (lastIndex > 0) {
                    filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
                }
                $('#txtImage').val(filename);
            });
        });

    </script>

<asp:FileUpload ID="Upload" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" /> 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtImage" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

TextBox txtImage does not have a closing tag.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtImage" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```